# Probabilistic sampling of non-adjacent cells in a raster - R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, sample

I'd like to sample non-adjacent cells from a raster using the raster cell values as their inclusion probability.

Here is an example of sampling cells from a raster which can result in adjacent cells being selected.

```
set.seed(1)
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(2500), nrow = 50, ncol = 50))
plot(r)

cells = sample(1:ncell(r), 100, prob=r[], replace=FALSE)

cell.centers = xyFromCell(r, cells)

plot(r)
points(cell.centers, pch = 19)
```

I realize with large sample sizes it would be nearly impossible to avoid selecting adjacent cells. In practice the number of samples I will be making is always going to be much smaller than the number of available cells. I just want to avoid including adjacent cells. I guess I could sample iteratively and remove cells once they are chosen..but that seems obtuse. Any help appreciated.